# Issue adding a second table entry during insert

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have set up a one-to-one relationship using EF6. My models are as follows (with unnecessary data removed):

```
public class Property
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Facilities Facilities { get; set; }
}
```

and...

```
public class Facilities
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Property")]
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }

    public virtual Property Property { get; set; }
}
```

What i want to achieve, is that when i create a 'property', i also create an entry in the facilities table, using the PropertyID that was just created. When i POST to create a property, nothing happens (it doesn't redirect to Index, and nothing is created in either table). There are no errors to help me understand what is going on? My controlller method is as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Description,BedroomCount,BathroomCount,GuestCount,StreetAddress,ZipCode,CommunityID,PropertyTypeID")] Property property, Facilities facilities)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            property.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            property.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            property.Status = 1;
            db.Property.Add(property);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            int lastPropertyID = db.Property.Max(item => item.ID);
            facilities.PropertyID = lastPropertyID;
            db.Facilities.Add(facilities);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CommunityID = new SelectList(db.Community, "ID", "Name", property.CommunityID);
        ViewBag.PropertyTypeID = new SelectList(db.PropertyType, "ID", "Name", property.PropertyTypeID);
        return View(property);
    }
```

Comment: Well, if i were you i would put the try/catch inside of the Create method to catch the error, it will be easier to fix the problem and help you out

Comment: Is `ModelState.IsValid` true? It's possible your model state is not valid and therefore it's not running the if block.

Comment: Did you try debugging and see what happens inside the if block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Entity Framework you don't need to save changes and then manually get IDs back, this is the only thing you need:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Description,BedroomCount,BathroomCount,GuestCount,StreetAddress,ZipCode,CommunityID,PropertyTypeID")] Property property, Facilities facilities)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        property.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        property.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        property.Status = 1;
        db.Property.Add(property);
        facilities.Property = property;
        db.Facilities.Add(facilities);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.CommunityID = new SelectList(db.Community, "ID", "Name", property.CommunityID);
    ViewBag.PropertyTypeID = new SelectList(db.PropertyType, "ID", "Name", property.PropertyTypeID);
    return View(property);
}
```

All the IDs will automatically be brought from DB when calling `SaveChanges` and the entities will be linked automatically. After you call `SaveChanges` you will notice that `ID` in `property` and `PropertyID` in `facilities` have been populated for you.